# Does Elasticsearch support AND query for multiple values?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

ElasticSearch v: 5.3

I've one items array store in elastic search.

```
userId: "123"
items: [
  {
    "range": {
      "from": 10,
      "to": 30
    },
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "range": {
      "from": 20,
      "to": 100
    },
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "range": {
      "from": 5,
      "to": 90
    },
    "id": "3"
  },
]
```

This is only single record. Consider this as multiple records which contains items key.
Now i want to perform search query with id and it's respected range. So my current query is like this

```
GET product/item/_search{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "items.id": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "items.range.from": {
              "gte": 20,
              "lte": 30
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "items.range.to": {
              "gte": 20,
              "lte": 30
            }
          }
        },

      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Currently this will perform a search query which has id=1 and range values from >= 20 and to <= 30. So it will return all the records containing id=2 and also which has range between 20 to 30. So even if in other records if id=1 is not present it will search for range values an will return records if range matches.

Instead of this i want to search for records which has id=1 and that id's value should between 20 to 30. 
So My question is does elastic search supports this kind of in between AND query?

Comment: Can you show the mapping of your index? Is the `items` field of type `nested`?

Comment: No. Its' not nested index. Sorry @Val this is one example input. My actual records very different and complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your `items` field to be [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) in your mapping, like this:

```
PUT product
{
  "mappings": {
    "item": {
      "properties": {
        "itemId": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "items": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "range": {
              "properties": {
                "from": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "to": {
                  "type": "long"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you'll be able to query like this:

```
GET product/item/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "items",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "items.id": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "items.range.from": {
                  "gte": 20,
                  "lte": 30
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "items.range.to": {
                  "gte": 20,
                  "lte": 30
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PS: I suggest that you look at the [`integer_range` data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html) instead of your `range.from/to` object. Just my two cents

Comment: OK. i'll test it out. If i'm going to use more keys then do i need to set mapping index for each of them or this range mapping is only required? Currently I've in my query there are Geo location search, normal text search and this range search.

Comment: You can keep the range as it is now, all I'm saying is that there' s a dedicated data type just for ranges that you might benefit from