# Querying and matching on 2 keys in a sub-object

Tags: elasticsearch

Hopefully I will be able to explain this issue clearly enough :/

I am trying to run a query on a resultset that returns a list of users who have liked an artist AND have a score of greater then or equal to 500.  Consider this index:

```
{
    "profile": 12345,
    "artists": [
        {
            "id": 135,
            "score": 10
        },
        {
            "id": 246,
            "score": 50
        },
        {
            "id": 1357,
            "score": 100
        }
    ]
},
{
    "profile": 24680,
    "artists": [
    {
        "id": 135,
        "score": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 246,
        "score": 500
    },
    {
        "id": 1357,
        "score": 77
    }
]
},
{
    "profile": 13579,
    "artists": [
        {
            "id": 135,
            "score": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 246,
            "score": 1000
        },
        {
            "id": 1357,
            "score": 150
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I would want to find users who have an artist.id value of 1357 AND have a score of greater then or equal to 100.  So, I would expect users 12345 and 13579 to be returned.  However, if I run the following query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "artists.key": "1357"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "artists.currentScore": {
                        "gte": 100
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then all three users are returned.  Because user 24680 has a score of greater than 100 on one of his results, despite it not being the id that I am passing, he is still being treated as a match.

Does anyone know of a way of matching both conditions, or at least when filtering, filtering on those where the original condition matched...

...if that makes any sense

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50055796/4604579

Comment: @Val - most likely the solution, however obviously the field in our index has been set up as non-nested, so not entirely we can easily go down that route.  Thanks a lot for the heads up though

Comment: You can certainly create a new index, change the mapping type accordingly and reindex your index into the new one.

Comment: True - we've done that so many times though I'm not sure how my manager would feel about it :D

Comment: Tell him it's hard to get the mapping correctly right from the beginning... new use cases, new needs, new data, new search queries that no one thought of, and the list goes on and on. How big is the index we're talking about?

Comment: Oh, nothing major, only 12,322,948 documents.  You're right though, every time we've re-indexed it has been down to encountering scenarios we never thought of at planning, such as being asked to return results on information such as this!

Comment: Piece of cake, between two roundtrips to the cafetaria ;-)